# Определение положения панели задач Delphi 7

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7

Как известно, панель задач можно закрепить слева\справа, снизу\сверху.
У меня панель задач находится сверху и при `Form1.Create` отображается за ней.
Можно ли в Delphi узнать, в какой из сторон находится панель задач?

Comment: позицию окна по центру поставьте да и все дела

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У объекта `Screen` есть два свойства - `DesktopRect` и `WorkAreaRect`.
В первом показываются координаты всего экрана, во втором - координаты "рабочей области" - это как раз экран за минусом таскбара.

Если нужно расположить окно так, чтобы оно не перекрывалось с таскбаром, то проверяем координаты прямоугольника окна и корректируем их так, чтобы оно не выходило за пределы `WorkAreaRect`. В простейшем случае поможет функция `IntersectRect()`.

Вот Вам примерчик, в котором окно ограничивается в размерах, чтобы не вылезать за пределы рабочей области.
Работает при любом выравнивании таскбара.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  da, wa, r, clip, me: TRect;
  s: string;
begin
  da := Screen.DesktopRect;
  wa := Screen.WorkAreaRect;
  s := Format('Screen.DesktopRect = { left: %d, top: %d, right: %d, bottom: %d }', [da.Left, da.Top, da.Right, da.Bottom]) + sLineBreak +
       Format('Screen.WorkAreaRect = { left: %d, top: %d, right: %d, bottom: %d }', [wa.Left, wa.Top, wa.Right, wa.Bottom]);

  Self.Left := 0;
  Self.Top := 0;
  Self.Width := Screen.Width;
  Self.Height := Screen.Height;

  Application.ProcessMessages();

  ShowMessage(s);

  // раскомментировать фрагменты, чтобы получить отступы от границ рабочей области
  clip := Rect(wa.Left {+ 25}, wa.Top {+ 25}, wa.Right {- 25}, wa.Bottom {- 25});
  me := Rect(Self.Left, Self.Top, Self.Left + Self.Width, Self.Top + Self.Height);

  if (IntersectRect(r, clip, me)) then
  begin
    Self.Left := r.Left;
    Self.Width := r.Right - r.Left;
    Self.Top := r.Top;
    Self.Height := r.Bottom - r.Top;
  end;
end;
```

Если необходима работа приложения в конфигурациях с несколькими мониторами, обращайтесь к свойству `Screen.Monitors`: в классе `TMonitor` имеются свойства `BoundsRect` и `WorkAreaRect`, с помощью которых тоже можно делать всё то же самое.

P.S.:
если всё-таки необходимо узнать выравнивание таскбара: можно заметить, что где у `Screen.WorkAreaRect` отличается координата (Left/Top/Right/Bottom) от соответствующей координаты в `Screen.DesktopRect`, там и лежит таскбар :)

Comment: панель задач может быть скрыта автоматически. в таком случае не прокатит.

Comment: согласен :) но если автору нужно только то, чтобы окно не перекрывалось с таскбаром, то наверное сгодится

Comment: в противном случае, вариантов немного - или в реестре почитать настройки, или попробовать найти таскбар через FindWindow()

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд, эффективнее воспользоваться стандартной функцией API  [SHAppBarMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762108(v=vs.85).aspx). Без FindWindow нам тоже не обойтись. Вот, набросал консольный пример, пока вспоминал, как работать с этой функцией. Работает в любом положении панели задач, не важно, скрытая она или нет.

```
program taskbarpos;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Windows,
  shellapi;

function FindTaskBarPos(var ARect: TRect): integer; / найти положение панели задач
// ARect - координаты, результат - положение, см. константы ниже
var
    AppData: TAppBarData;
begin
  AppData.Hwnd := FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd', nil);
  if AppData.Hwnd = 0 then
    RaiseLastWin32Error; // на всякий случай :)
  AppData.cbSize := SizeOf(TAppBarData);
  if SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, AppData) = 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('SHAppBarMessage возвратило ошибку при попытке обращения к позиции Панели задач');
  Result := AppData.uEdge;
  ARect := AppData.rc;
end;

var
  tr:TRect;
  edge:integer;

begin
  edge:=FindTaskBarPos(tr);
  case edge of
     ABE_BOTTOM:
          Writeln('Снизу');
     ABE_LEFT:
          Writeln('Слева');
     ABE_RIGHT:
          Writeln('Справа');
     ABE_TOP:
          Writeln('Сверху');
  end;
  Writeln('Правая координата:' +  IntToStr(tr.Right)+' нижняя координата:' + IntToStr(tr.Bottom)); 
end.
```

`tr.Left` и `tr.Top` вернут, соответственно, координаты левой части и верхней.